# Find a specific char element in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am trying to find the first space in my `Array` so I can predict the length of a word, and at the same time count the amount of `char` elements before the space. I am always getting an infinite loop.

Please help me. This is my Code:

```
int counter=0;                      
int i=0;

while(counter==0) {
    if (field[i]==' ') {
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        if (i==field.length-1) {
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference: `for (i=0; i<field.length && field[i]!=' '; ++i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a WHILE function? I think you can do something like this:

```
int iCharecters = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i< word.length;i++) {
    if ( word[i] == " " ) {
        break;
    } else {
        iCharecters ++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to find first space char in array you can use stream API:

```
Boolean spacePresent = Arrays.stream(chars)
                             .anyMatch(it -> it == ' ')
```